# php file_get_contents with ajax content

Tags: php, ajax, file-get-contents

I have used `file_get_contents` function to get content of a website. However it doesn't load the content that displayed in an Ajax.
How can I get fully content after the ajax complete?

```
echo file_get_contents("thewebsiteurl");
```

I mean in the `thewebsiteurl` has an Ajax, and content ABC displayed after this ajax. When I use `file_get_contents` to get the content of the `thewebsiteurl`, I can not get the ABC content.

Thanks

Comment: You'd need a headless browser which can execute javascript

Comment: What do you want? Please give more information and make it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean.

What I do get out of it is that you're trying to send data with Ajax.
This data then needs to get processed in PHP.

Ajax automatically encode the data with JSON for you. This means that in you php code you should use

```
json_decode();
```

I hope this was the answer to your vague question.

Comment: I updated my question, hope it's more clear. Thanks

Comment: You're trying to get the data that will be received from the ajax call?

Comment: Yes. but from the thewebsiteurl